# Flutter: show Circularprogressindicator while build Googlemap

Tags: google-maps, flutter

I want to show `circularprogressindicator()` until `Googlemap` build is finished.

I used `FutureBuilder`, but it didn't work.

my code

```
Container(
  height:100,
  child: FutureBuilder(
    future: googlemap()
    builder: (context, snapshot){
      if(snapshot.hasdata){
        return snapshot.data;
      }
      else{
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    }
  )
)
```

Futurbuilder

```
Futur<Widget>  googlemap() async{
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();
  return await Googlemap(
    mapType: MapType.normal,
    initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
      target: LatLng(XX.XXXXXX, XXX.XXXXXX),
      zoom: 17.0
    )
    onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller){
      _controller.complete(controller);
    },
    myLocationEnabled: false,
    myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
    compassEnabled: false,
    zoomGesturesEnabled: false,
    rotateGesturesEnabled: false,
    scrollGesturesEnabled: false,
    tiltGesturesEnabled: false,
    markers: Set<Marker>.of(_markers)
  )
}
```

result

[image]

can i get some tips in here?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solved it yet, but I found an alternative.

my solution

```
  bool splash = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), (){
      setState(() {
        splash = true;
      });
    });
  }
```

Widget

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return splash ? SafeArea(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          //googlemap1(),
          //googlemap2(),
          //googlemap3(),
          //googlemap4(),
        ],
      ),
    ) : Container(
      child: Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator()
      ),
    );
  }
```

please let me know if there is a better way than this.